# Can I turn power off iPhone via App?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to make a sleep app for iPhone? It's like user sets a time and on that time the iphone automatically turns off.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Apple has a strict policy about app permission. There is a parental lock system, but i am not sure how it works. You have to research.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. There is no public APIs available for switching off iOS device.